# Wifi connection when using mobile network

Tags: wifi, 3g, roaming

When I change my network from 3G to Wifi what is happening to all the services I'm using (like Facebook, Gmail, etc.)? Do they disconnect and then connect again? Is it like roaming between mobile networks?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are disconnected and they have to reconnect. I checked that in my own Android app. There I'm handling mobile and wifi network strength and on change the device is offline.

Since you change your connection you will get another IP which requires to reconnect.